# Why did this happen to Pate in A Feast for Crows?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Do we have any good in-universe explanations why, at the start of *A Feast for Crows*,

> Pate was killed by the alchemist/Jaqen H'ghar?

Comment: The Alchemist infiltrated the citadel, he introduced himself to Sam at the end of the book.

Comment: And Pate was necessary because he was close to AM Marwyn, right?

Comment: I'm currently rereading but my memory of AFFC is hazy.

Comment: We don't know Jaqen's motivations.

Comment: Sure, I'm speculating, was hoping you'd want to play ball.

Comment: Not sure Marwyn is what/who he is interested in, considering that Marwyn leaves but Pate does not.

Comment: Archmaester Marwyn, or Marwyn the Mage. He tutored Mirri Maz Duur in healing and IIRC had some connection to Pate.

Comment: @LeoKing We know that Jaqen is a Faceless man. Their organisation was founded as a resistance against the Valyrian freehold, magic users and slavers. We also know from Marwyn that the citadel has certain anti-magic (e.g. Targaryen, dragon) tendencies. That *might* align Jaqen against Dany. But on the other hand, since he is infiltrating the place, more likely he is not with them. But really.. not enough to speculate on.

Comment: Of course, Jaqen's mission started well before the birth of Dany's dragons, when Ned was still hand of the king (when Ned gave Yoren the "pick of the dungeons", and Jaqen was there).

Answer (score 8):

Later on in [Chapter 45 of AFFC](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/A_Feast_for_Crows-Chapter_45),

> Sam Tarly meets a novice named Pate with [the same features](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Alchemist) as Pate from the prologue. Since Jaqen H'ghar is a faceless man, he has presumably assumed Pate's identity, and this is why Pate was killed. Unfortunately as of the end of ADWD we do not know what Jaqen is ultimately trying to accomplish.